# How can I predict using an AFT model with the survival package in R?

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis, weibull

I am using an [accelerated failure time / AFT model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_failure_time_model) with a [weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) to predict data. I am doing this using the [survival package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html) in R. I am splitting my data in training and test, do training on the training set and afterwards try to predict the values for the test set. To do that I am passing the the test set as the `newdata` parameter, as stated in the [references](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/predict.survreg.html). I get an error, saying that `newdata` does not have the same size as the training data (obviously!). Then the function seems to evaluate predict the values for the training set.

**How can I predict the values for the new data?**

```
# get data
library(KMsurv)
library(survival)
data("kidtran") 
n = nrow(kidtran)
kidtran <- kidtran[sample(n),] # shuffle row-wise
kidtran.train = kidtran[1:(n * 0.8),]
kidtran.test = kidtran[(n * 0.8):n,]

# create model 
aftmodel <- survreg(kidtransurv~kidtran.train$gender+kidtran.train$race+kidtran.train$age, dist = "weibull")
predicted <- predict(aftmodel, newdata = kidtran.test)
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by Hack-R, there was this line of code missing

```
kidtransurv <- Surv(kidtran.train$time, kidtran.train$delta)
```

Comment: I added your missing `library` statements that jumped out at me. We're still missing `kidtransurv` though.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It looks like I guessed correctly which columns you wanted in Y. You need to type it the way I did in my answer though (keeping the definition in the `survreg` function). Using `data = ` is not required, however it cleans up your code a lot and reduces the typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your specification of the dependent variable.

The data and code definition of the dependent was missing from your question, so I can't see what the specific mistake was, but it did not appear to be a proper `Surv()` survival object (see `?survreg`).

This variation on your code fixes that, makes some minor formatting improvements, and runs fine:

```
require(survival)
pacman::p_load(KMsurv)

library(KMsurv)
library(survival)
data("kidtran") 

n = nrow(kidtran)

kidtran       <- kidtran[sample(n),] 
kidtran.train <- kidtran[1:(n * 0.8),]
kidtran.test  <- kidtran[(n * 0.8):n,]

# Whatever kidtransurv was supposed to be is missing from your question,
#   so I will replace it with something not-missing
#   and I will make it into a proper survival object with Surv()

aftmodel  <- survreg(Surv(time, delta) ~ gender + race + age, dist = "weibull", data = kidtran.train)
predicted <- predict(aftmodel, newdata = kidtran.test)


head(predicted)
```

> ```
>        302        636        727        121         85        612 
>  33190.413  79238.898 111401.546  16792.180   4601.363  17698.895
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working now. I assumed that defining `kidtransurv <- Surv(kidtran.train$time, kidtran.train$delta)` prior to the definition of the model would be equivalent to your version

Comment: @User12547645 You're welcome. I might've thought that too at first.